# What is meant by integrable equation/system?

Tags: dynamical-systems

In mathematical physics one frequently encounters the idea of an integrable equation/system. E.g., people talk about integrability of Schrodinger's Equation and KdV equation. To be frank, I can't understand the mumbo-jumbo written in Wikipedia article on [Integrable Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system). Can anyone explain in a simpler manner? And what is exactly a scattering transform?

Comment: As Wikipedia clearly says "there are various distinct notions that are referred to under the name of integrable systems". We can't guess for you.

Comment: Atleast can you explain the section on "Solitons and inverse spectral methods"

Answer (score 2):

We refer to a system to be integrable if the number of symmetries $N_s$ and the number of degrees of freedoms $N_\text{dof}$ obey the relation

$N_s \ge N_\text{dof}$

For example the two bodies in three dimensional space have 2 times 3 degrees of freedom. So $N_\text{dof} = 6$ And we have the following symmetries

- three translations
- three rotations
- energy conservation

so we have $N_s = 7$ and therefore an integrable system.

While the famous three body problem has $9$ degrees of freedom but also only $7$ symmetries it is not integrable (and that is also part of the difficulty of the three body problem)

---

Edit example how to integrate a system.

the harmonic Oscilator $\ddot x = - k x$ Has one variable $x$ so one degree of freedom, it preserves the energy $E = \dot x^2 + k x^2 $ this what we would call a symmetry (it is time translation symmetry by the way (if you are interested read about Noether's theorem)).

Now if we want to integrate that system we can start by computing the Energy of that initial state. Since we know that this energy does not change we can rearange the equation for the energy $\sqrt{E - k x^2} = \dot x  $

and then

$\sqrt{E - k x^2}dt = dx $

$dt = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{E - k x^2}} $

and now all we need to do is integrate that relation to obtain $t(x)$ inverting that function gives us $x(t)$ and we have solved for the motion.

Comment: Is this this fancy language for no. of variables should eual no. of independent eqations

Comment: No, i mean that is what you would need in order to be sure that there exists a solution. Let me expand my answer in order to demonstrate how to integrate a system that has a symmetry.

Comment: The second part of my question is related to scattering, any comments on that. E.g.- the section on "Solitons & Inverse Spectral Methods" in the wiki article.